# Problem with BeautifulSoup not finding tables

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am currently working on a web scraper that collects data from [basketball-reference](http://basketball-reference.com) to use for some analytics projects. I am currently writing a function that finds game logs for specific players for specific dates. I am stumped because it works perfectly for certain players (Kobe Bryant, Thabo Sefolosha) but returns nothing for others.

Here is the code that gathers game logs:

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    from requests import get
    import pandas as pd
    def get_game_logs(name, start_date, end_date, playoffs=False):
        suffix = get_player_suffix(name).replace('/', '%2F').replace('.html', '')
        start_date_str = start_date
        end_date_str = end_date
        start_date = pd.to_datetime(start_date)
        end_date = pd.to_datetime(end_date)
        years = list(range(start_date.year, end_date.year+2))
        if playoffs: selector = 'div_pgl_basic_playoffs'
        else: selector = 'div_pgl_basic'
        final_df = None
        for year in years:
            print(years)
            r = get(f'https://widgets.sports-reference.com/wg.fcgi?css=1&site=bbr&url={suffix}%2Fgamelog%2F{year}&div={selector}')
            if r.status_code==200:
                soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
                table = soup.find('table')
                if table:
                    df = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]
                    active_df = pd.DataFrame(columns = list(df.columns))
                    for index, row in df.iterrows():
                        if len(row['GS'])>1: continue
                        active_df = active_df.append(row)
                    if final_df is None:
                        final_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=list(active_df.columns))
                    final_df = final_df.append(active_df)
        return final_df
```

Specifically, running get_game_logs('Kobe Bryant', '2013-08-01', '2014-02-02') gets me the games he played during that time period, whereas running get_game_logs('DeMarcus Cousins', '2013-08-01', '2014-02-02') returns None. I think the problem lies in the fact the html code is being parsed, since the table itself is empty. However, seeing as near identical inputs have different result, and the url contents are the same for both players, I am very confused as to what could be causing this.

Comment: good day and hello dear NeonCop - i have tried to run your example on a fresh installed ATOM on Win 10... see the results:   `File "C:\Users\Kasper\Documents\_mk_\_dev_\python\_examples_\kobe.py", line 4
    def get_game_logs(name, start_date, end_date, playoffs=False):
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
[Finished in 0.134s]` any idea!? love to hear from you

Comment: @zero sorry, I had the function definition at a different level than the import statements, should be fine now. Please let me know if you have any further results!

Comment: Works fine for me. share your `get_player_suffix(name)` function, I suspect that's the issue

Comment: Nevermind, I just rewrote for you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm suspecting the issue is with the get_player_suffix (although I don't know how you have that function working.) To get the player url id, for MOST it just redirects to the correct site, however for some players, the suffix might not follow the same format of last 5 letters of last name + first 2 letters of first name followed by the number 01 (Ie `bryanko01`). For example, Anthony Davis is `davisan02`.

For `DeMarcus Cousins`, it does still follow that format, but if you search for his name, it takes you search results, rather than redirect to his page like it does for Kobe.

So what I did is re-wrote the `get_player_suffix` function to say, if it returns search results, choose which player you want, and it'll go on it's merry way. Other wise, if it redirect to the page, then it's just going to go:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests import get
import pandas as pd


def get_player_suffix(name):
    searchUrl = 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/search/search.fcgi'
    payload = {'hint': name,
               'search': name}
    response = get(searchUrl, params=payload)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

    if soup.find('h1').text == 'Search Results':
        players = soup.find('h1').find_next('div').find_all('a', href=True)
        playerChoices = {}
        for each in players:
            if 'players/%s/' %(name.split()[-1][0].lower()) in each['href']:
                playerChoices[each.text] = each['href']

        if len(playerChoices.keys()) > 1:
            print ('Make a choice:')
            for idx, player in enumerate(playerChoices.keys()):
                print ('   %s: %s' %(idx, player))
            playerUrl = playerChoices[list(playerChoices.keys())[int(input('\nEnter number: '))]].replace('.html', '') 
        else:
            playerUrl = playerChoices[list(playerChoices.keys())[0]].replace('.html', '') 

    else:
        playerUrl = response.url.split('.com')[-1].replace('.html', '')  

    return playerUrl




def get_game_logs(name, start_date, end_date, playoffs=False):
    suffix = get_player_suffix(name).replace('/', '%2F')

    start_date_str = start_date
    end_date_str = end_date
    start_date = pd.to_datetime(start_date)
    end_date = pd.to_datetime(end_date)
    years = list(range(start_date.year, end_date.year+2))
    if playoffs: selector = 'div_pgl_basic_playoffs'
    else: selector = 'div_pgl_basic'
    final_df = None
    for year in years:
        print(year)
        url = f'https://widgets.sports-reference.com/wg.fcgi?css=1&site=bbr&url={suffix}%2Fgamelog%2F{year}&div={selector}'
        r = get(url)
        if r.status_code==200:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
            table = soup.find('table')
            if table:
                df = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]
                active_df = pd.DataFrame(columns = list(df.columns))
                for index, row in df.iterrows():
                    if len(row['GS'])>1: continue
                    active_df = active_df.append(row)
                if final_df is None:
                    final_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=list(active_df.columns))
                final_df = final_df.append(active_df)
    return final_df
```

**Output:**

```
df2 = get_game_logs('Anthony Davis', '2017-08-01', '2019-02-02')      
Make a choice:
   0: Anthony Davis (2013-2020)
   1: Mark Davis (1996-2000)


Enter number:
```

Then input `0`

```
print (df2)
    Rk   G        Date     Age   Tm Unnamed: 5  ... BLK TOV PF PTS  GmSc  +/-
0    1   1  2016-10-26  23-229  NOP        NaN  ...   4   3  4  50  44.2   -3
1    2   2  2016-10-28  23-231  NOP        NaN  ...   2   1  2  45  39.7   -3
2    3   3  2016-10-29  23-232  NOP          @  ...   3   1  1  18  11.3  -17
3    4   4  2016-11-01  23-235  NOP        NaN  ...   3   1  2  35  33.9   +3
4    5   5  2016-11-02  23-236  NOP          @  ...   3   5  5  10   1.6  -23
5    6   6  2016-11-04  23-238  NOP        NaN  ...   4   1  1  22  22.7   -6
6    7   7  2016-11-07  23-241  NOP          @  ...   0   3  1  33  25.2   -6
7    8   8  2016-11-08  23-242  NOP          @  ...   4   3  2  34  28.3   -4
8    9   9  2016-11-10  23-244  NOP          @  ...   4   2  3  30  24.2   +7
9   10  10  2016-11-12  23-246  NOP        NaN  ...   2   1  0  34  24.4  -10
10  11  11  2016-11-14  23-248  NOP        NaN  ...   2   7  2  25  14.4    0
12  13  12  2016-11-18  23-252  NOP        NaN  ...   4   2  2  38  36.3  +16
13  14  13  2016-11-19  23-253  NOP        NaN  ...   3   2  3  38  31.2   +7
14  15  14  2016-11-22  23-256  NOP          @  ...   3   2  1  13  10.1  +13
15  16  15  2016-11-23  23-257  NOP        NaN  ...   1   4  1  45  36.3  +33
16  17  16  2016-11-25  23-259  NOP          @  ...   5   1  1  31  28.9  -16
17  18  17  2016-11-27  23-261  NOP          @  ...   1   2  3  36  30.3  -19
18  19  18  2016-11-29  23-263  NOP        NaN  ...   2   1  4  41  39.0  +19
19  20  19  2016-12-02  23-266  NOP        NaN  ...   1   2  2  21  15.9   -7
21  21  20  2016-12-04  23-268  NOP          @  ...   4   3  3  37  27.9  -10
22  22  21  2016-12-05  23-269  NOP        NaN  ...   4   1  1  28  21.0   -5
23  23  22  2016-12-08  23-272  NOP        NaN  ...   2   3  1  26  16.8  -10
25  25  23  2016-12-11  23-275  NOP          @  ...   2   3  4  14   9.1   -7
26  26  24  2016-12-13  23-277  NOP        NaN  ...   5   6  2  28  25.0   -8
27  27  25  2016-12-15  23-279  NOP        NaN  ...   5   4  2  35  25.3  +14
28  28  26  2016-12-16  23-280  NOP          @  ...   0   1  0  19  12.9  -15
29  29  27  2016-12-18  23-282  NOP          @  ...   1   3  4  12   3.6  -23
30  30  28  2016-12-20  23-284  NOP          @  ...   2   1  2  31  21.4  +11
31  31  29  2016-12-21  23-285  NOP        NaN  ...   2   2  5  34  25.4   +6
32  32  30  2016-12-23  23-287  NOP        NaN  ...   4   3  3  28  28.6   +4
..  ..  ..         ...     ...  ...        ...  ...  ..  .. ..  ..   ...  ...
27  27  26  2019-12-15  26-279  LAL          @  ...   2   5  5  27  16.7   -3
29  29  27  2019-12-19  26-283  LAL          @  ...   3   1  4  36  29.9   +6
30  30  28  2019-12-22  26-286  LAL        NaN  ...   4   5  4  32  22.9  -13
31  31  29  2019-12-25  26-289  LAL        NaN  ...   2   3  4  24  18.0  -10
32  32  30  2019-12-28  26-292  LAL          @  ...   0   2  3  20  16.6   +6
33  33  31  2019-12-29  26-293  LAL        NaN  ...   1   4  2  23  20.8  +16
34  34  32  2020-01-01  26-296  LAL        NaN  ...   1   3  1  26  20.4  +16
35  35  33  2020-01-03  26-298  LAL        NaN  ...   1   3  3  46  42.2  +26
36  36  34  2020-01-05  26-300  LAL        NaN  ...   8   0  3  24  27.7  -11
37  37  35  2020-01-07  26-302  LAL        NaN  ...   2   3  2   5   5.7  +10
44  43  36  2020-01-20  26-315  LAL          @  ...   2   2  5   9   6.7  -24
45  44  37  2020-01-22  26-317  LAL          @  ...   2   1  0  28  27.8   +8
46  45  38  2020-01-23  26-318  LAL          @  ...   1   2  3  16  14.5   +6
47  46  39  2020-01-25  26-320  LAL          @  ...   1   5  3  31  20.4  -10
48  47  40  2020-01-31  26-326  LAL        NaN  ...   5   4  1  37  37.1  -13
49  48  41  2020-02-01  26-327  LAL          @  ...   1   2  1  21  22.8  +20
50  49  42  2020-02-04  26-330  LAL        NaN  ...   0   4  1  18  12.3   +7
51  50  43  2020-02-06  26-332  LAL        NaN  ...   3   0  3  32  32.8   -4
52  51  44  2020-02-08  26-334  LAL          @  ...   1   2  2  27  26.7   +4
53  52  45  2020-02-10  26-336  LAL        NaN  ...   1   3  2  25  21.9   +9
54  53  46  2020-02-12  26-338  LAL          @  ...   2   2  2  33  25.9   +5
55  54  47  2020-02-21  26-347  LAL        NaN  ...   7   4  2  28  27.1  +11
56  55  48  2020-02-23  26-349  LAL        NaN  ...   2   6  3  32  19.9   -3
57  56  49  2020-02-25  26-351  LAL        NaN  ...   6   2  3  21  19.0  +11
58  57  50  2020-02-27  26-353  LAL          @  ...   2   3  2  23  18.0  +17
59  58  51  2020-02-29  26-355  LAL          @  ...   2   1  2  15  14.9  -10
61  60  52  2020-03-03  26-358  LAL        NaN  ...   2   2  1  37  38.0  +30
63  61  53  2020-03-06  26-361  LAL        NaN  ...   2   4  4  30  16.9   +8
64  62  54  2020-03-08  26-363  LAL          @  ...   1   1  5  30  23.9  +12
65  63  55  2020-03-10  26-365  LAL        NaN  ...   1   1  4  26  18.6   -5

[261 rows x 30 columns]
```

Then running `df3 = get_game_logs('DeMarcus Cousins', '2013-08-01', '2014-02-02')`

you get **Output:**

```
print (df3)
    Rk   G        Date     Age   Tm Unnamed: 5  ... BLK TOV PF PTS  GmSc  +/-
0    1   1  2012-10-31  22-079  SAC          @  ...   2   7  4  14   6.8  -12
1    2   2  2012-11-02  22-081  SAC          @  ...   0   1  5  11   2.1   -5
2    3   3  2012-11-03  22-082  SAC          @  ...   1   1  4  21  14.0   -8
3    4   4  2012-11-05  22-084  SAC        NaN  ...   2   3  2  23  21.8   +1
4    5   5  2012-11-07  22-086  SAC        NaN  ...   0   1  2  21  16.2   -8
5    6   6  2012-11-09  22-088  SAC        NaN  ...   0   2  5  14   8.8   -7
8    9   7  2012-11-16  22-095  SAC        NaN  ...   0   2  3   9  10.2  -19
9   10   8  2012-11-18  22-097  SAC        NaN  ...   1   4  3  29  20.8   -2
10  11   9  2012-11-21  22-100  SAC        NaN  ...   0   3  6   7   0.7  +10
11  12  10  2012-11-23  22-102  SAC          @  ...   2   4  4  14   8.6   -1
12  13  11  2012-11-24  22-103  SAC        NaN  ...   0   2  3  14  11.1   +2
13  14  12  2012-11-27  22-106  SAC        NaN  ...   0   2  4  20  11.1   -1
14  15  13  2012-11-30  22-109  SAC        NaN  ...   0   2  1  19  15.8   -6
15  16  14  2012-12-01  22-110  SAC          @  ...   0   2  2   8   2.6  -19
16  17  15  2012-12-05  22-114  SAC        NaN  ...   1   4  3  25  17.7  +10
17  18  16  2012-12-07  22-116  SAC        NaN  ...   2   4  2  17  16.1   +6
18  19  17  2012-12-08  22-117  SAC          @  ...   0   0  2  19  15.1  +13
19  20  18  2012-12-10  22-119  SAC          @  ...   0   4  2  25  17.4  -12
22  22  19  2012-12-14  22-123  SAC          @  ...   1   2  0  10   6.8   -6
23  23  20  2012-12-16  22-125  SAC        NaN  ...   0   1  3  19  14.6  -22
24  24  21  2012-12-17  22-126  SAC          @  ...   0   3  4   9   3.0  -15
25  25  22  2012-12-19  22-128  SAC        NaN  ...   1   5  5  24  18.5   +6
26  26  23  2012-12-21  22-130  SAC          @  ...   1   2  0   9   8.2   -9
29  29  24  2012-12-28  22-137  SAC        NaN  ...   1   2  5  15  14.2   +6
30  30  25  2012-12-30  22-139  SAC        NaN  ...   0   2  5  12  13.0  +21
31  31  26  2013-01-01  22-141  SAC          @  ...   0   2  5  21  17.7   -7
32  32  27  2013-01-02  22-142  SAC          @  ...   1   1  3  18  21.2  +13
33  33  28  2013-01-04  22-144  SAC          @  ...   0   4  4  31  29.2  +18
34  34  29  2013-01-05  22-145  SAC          @  ...   1   0  3  28  26.3  -14
35  35  30  2013-01-07  22-147  SAC        NaN  ...   0   4  3  10   4.2  -21
..  ..  ..         ...     ...  ...        ...  ...  ..  .. ..  ..   ...  ...
43  42  30  2015-01-21  24-161  SAC        NaN  ...   0   2  3  28  21.5  +11
44  43  31  2015-01-23  24-163  SAC          @  ...   0   5  4  28  19.8   -9
45  44  32  2015-01-28  24-168  SAC          @  ...   2   9  4  13   4.8   -4
46  45  33  2015-01-30  24-170  SAC          @  ...   1   3  2  21  20.9  -15
47  46  34  2015-01-31  24-171  SAC          @  ...   0   4  6  20  12.0   +7
48  47  35  2015-02-03  24-174  SAC        NaN  ...   4   3  3  26  23.8  -14
49  48  36  2015-02-05  24-176  SAC        NaN  ...   2   6  3  23  15.6  -22
50  49  37  2015-02-07  24-178  SAC          @  ...   2   4  6  27  12.8  -11
51  50  38  2015-02-08  24-179  SAC        NaN  ...   2   6  3  28  14.9   +2
52  51  39  2015-02-10  24-181  SAC          @  ...   1   2  4  15  10.0  -16
53  52  40  2015-02-11  24-182  SAC          @  ...   4   6  4  28  23.6    0
54  53  41  2015-02-20  24-191  SAC        NaN  ...   1   9  3  31  22.7  -10
55  54  42  2015-02-21  24-192  SAC          @  ...   2   5  4  21   8.7  -12
56  55  43  2015-02-25  24-196  SAC        NaN  ...   1   2  6  16  13.5   +9
59  58  44  2015-03-03  24-202  SAC          @  ...   2   3  3  22  21.3  +19
60  59  45  2015-03-04  24-203  SAC          @  ...   2   5  4  14   5.5   -7
61  60  46  2015-03-06  24-205  SAC          @  ...   3   1  2  29  25.7   -8
63  61  47  2015-03-07  24-206  SAC          @  ...   1   5  6  27  23.6   -6
64  62  48  2015-03-09  24-208  SAC          @  ...   0   1  2  12  16.1  -22
65  63  49  2015-03-11  24-210  SAC          @  ...   0   4  4  20  12.2   -3
66  64  50  2015-03-13  24-212  SAC          @  ...   1   3  2  39  35.4   +5
67  65  51  2015-03-14  24-213  SAC          @  ...   1   3  6  30  21.5   -7
68  66  52  2015-03-16  24-215  SAC        NaN  ...   3   5  5  20  14.0   -4
71  69  53  2015-03-22  24-221  SAC        NaN  ...   0   5  5  20  16.3   +5
72  70  54  2015-03-24  24-223  SAC        NaN  ...   4   3  5  33  29.5   -2
73  71  55  2015-03-25  24-224  SAC          @  ...   1   5  2  24  17.4   +8
74  72  56  2015-03-27  24-226  SAC          @  ...   3   3  3  39  33.3   -1
76  74  57  2015-04-01  24-231  SAC          @  ...   6   5  4  24  25.6   +1
77  75  58  2015-04-03  24-233  SAC        NaN  ...   3   5  5  24  21.8   +7
78  76  59  2015-04-05  24-235  SAC        NaN  ...   1   8  2  26  13.9   -1

[205 rows x 30 columns]
```